# How can I make a shader or change the scene lighting to make glass less reflective?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, lighting, glass

How can I adjust the lighting and create a glass shader to make an object less reflective like these:
[image: This picture was taken from "The Cleverest" intro]
[image: This picture was taken from "The Cleverest" intro]
I tried this:
[image: The shader's graph]
But it doesn't reflect at all:
[image: The whole scene]

Comment: What you want is not clear, do you want to create a more reflecting glass? Because it looks like what you've done is not reflective at all... By the way don't use a Diffuse node, only mix between Glass, Transparent, Glossy...

Comment: Yeah, not too reflective, not too non-reflective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the basic node organization for glass is a mix between *Glass* and *Transparency*. The more your mix will tend to *Transparency* (*Mix Shader* value) the less it will be reflective. The *Glass Roughness* will make the glass more polished.

You can mix that with a *Glossy Shader* with a *Layer Weight* as factor if you want to add reflectivity on the normals for more realism, and same thing, play with the *Layer Weight* value.

[image]

Comment: By following your shader I get this: https://photos.app.goo.gl/94vkpDyG2o7oono58. There are 3 suns in my scene with a strength of 2, 3, 5 respectively.

Comment: so as I say you need to play with the values  ;)  more transparency for example